# Блокирование третьей кнопки при активных двух

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, использую vanilla JS,
есть три кнопки категорий, максимум может быть нажато две кнопки, если две кнопки нажато на третью нажать нельзя. Могут быть нажаты любые 2 кнопки из трёх, при этом третья должна блокироваться (disabled).

```
const categoriesButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.service__button');

categoriesButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (event.target.id === 'gardens') {
            button.classList.toggle('button--active');
        }
        else if (event.target.id === 'lawn') {
            button.classList.toggle('button--active');  

        } else if (event.target.id === 'planting') {
            button.classList.toggle('button--active');
        }
        
        // if (event.target.id === 'gardens' && event.target.id === 'lawn') {
        //     plantingBtn.classList.add('.button--disabled')
        // }  => Этот код не работает
    })
})
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос разметку и стили относящиеся к этим кнопкам.

Comment: `event.target.id === 'gardens' && event.target.id === 'lawn'` это не будет работать, т.к. в один момент врмени(тыка на кнопку) есть только один id

Answer (score 0):

При нажатых 2х кнопках, оставшейся будет установлен нужный класс. Если кнопку отжать, класс удаляется

```js
const categoriesButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.service__button');
const selectButtons = []; // Нажатые кнопки
const allButtons = []; // Все кнопки
let disabledButton = ''; // С признаком disable

categoriesButtons.forEach((button) => {
  allButtons.push(button.id); // Записываем в справочник все найденные
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // Добавляем или удаляем кнопку
    if (selectButtons.includes(event.target.id)) {
      selectButtons.splice(selectButtons.indexOf(event.target.id), 1)
    } else {
      selectButtons.push(event.target.id)
    }

    if (event.target.id === 'gardens') {
      button.classList.toggle('button--active');
    }
    else if (event.target.id === 'lawn') {
      button.classList.toggle('button--active');

    } else if (event.target.id === 'planting') {
      button.classList.toggle('button--active');
    }
    // Проверяем, если нажато 2, то оставшейся добавляем стиль
    if (selectButtons.length === 2) {
      disabledButton = allButtons.filter(it => !selectButtons.includes(it))[0];
      document.getElementById(disabledButton).classList.add('button--disabled');
    } else if (disabledButton) { // Иначе стиль удаляем
      document.getElementById(disabledButton)?.classList.remove('button--disabled');
      disabledButton = '';
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.service__button {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

.button--active {
  background-color: #11AA11;
}

.button--disabled {
  background-color: #FF5555;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="service__button" id="gardens">тык раз</button>
<button class="service__button" id="lawn">тык два</button>
<button class="service__button" id="planting">тык три</button>
```

Comment: Приветствую, SwaD! Как дела?) Не забудь про магическое число ;)

Comment: @SIDJO Что за число такое, магическое?

Comment: Цифра 2 - это от куда? Если будет 10 кнопок?

Comment: @SIDJO это из вопроса

Comment: Я сделал динамическое число, но на самом деле лучше сделать глобальную переменную. Первое - что-бы не лезть в код, исправлять, второе смотришь на переменную и понимаешь от куда взялось 2. Например const MAX_ACTIVE_COUNT = 2 P.S. я надеюсь Евгений в отдельном модуле все пишет ;)

Comment: @SIDJO Читайте что спрашивают... 3 кнопки, 2 нажаты. Все. В вопросе нет миллиона кнопок. Так что под задачу есть ответ. Если бы было х кнопок y нажато, было бы другое решение предложено

Comment: да вообще не вопрос) Если, что не обессудь)) вот в вики про это есть) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142505/discussion-between-sid-jo-and-swad).

Answer (score 0):

Евгений, для поведения кнопок, которое Вы описали в вопросе, лучше подошли бы чекбоксы. Да, в разметке придется написать немного больше кода, но это будет правильный подход.

```js
// За всю отрисовку состояния инпутов отвечает одна функция, опираясь на данные из состояния.
const render = (state, controls) => {
  const activeCount = Object.values(state).filter(v => v === 'checked').length // Здесь получаем количество 'чекнутых' инпутов

  if (activeCount === state.maxActiveCount) { // Никаких магических чисел.
    controls.forEach(input =>
      state[input.dataset.service] === 'checked' // input.dataset.service - достает значение из data атрибута в инпуте
        ? input.setAttribute("checked", "")
        : input.setAttribute("disabled", "")
    )
  } else {
    controls.forEach(input =>
      state[input.dataset.service] === 'checked'
        ? input.setAttribute("checked", "")
        : input.removeAttribute("disabled")
    )
  }
}

/* Здесь используем замыкание функции для доступа к состоянию. Реализуем сосотяние опираясь на количество инпутов. В реальных приложениях лучше использовать proxy или библиотеку для подписки на изменения состояния */
const createHandler = (controls = []) => {
  const state = controls.reduce((acc, input) => {
    const value = input.dataset.service
    return {...acc, [value]: 'idle'}
  },{maxActiveCount: 3}) // Как обсуждалось в комментариях добавим переменную которая регулирует количество активных кнопок

  return ({target}) => { // Это обработчик событий
    const value = target.dataset.service
    state[value] = state[value] === 'idle' ? 'checked' : 'idle'
    render(state, controls)
  }
}

// Здесь находим форму и делигируем события инпутов на один обработчик событий
const service = document.getElementById('service')
const serviceControls = Array.from(service.elements)
const handleChange = createHandler(serviceControls)
service.addEventListener("change", handleChange)
```

```css
.service {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: slateblue;
}

.control input { /*прячем инпут*/
  appearance: none;
}

.control__button {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-wrap: none;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.service__control input:checked + .control__button {
  background-color: #11AA11;
}

.service__control input:disabled + .control__button {
  background-color: #FF5555;
}
```

```html
<form class='service' id="service">
    <label class="control service__control">
        <input type="checkbox" data-service="gardens" />
        <span class="control__button">тык раз</span>
    </label>
    <label class="control service__control">
        <input type="checkbox" data-service="lawn" />
        <span class="control__button"> тык два</span>
    </label>
    <label class="control service__control">
        <input type="checkbox" data-service="planting" />
        <span class="control__button">тык три</span>
    </label>
    <label class="control service__control">
        <input type="checkbox" data-service="fourth-button" />
        <span class="control__button">тык четыре</span>
    </label>
    <label class="control service__control">
        <input type="checkbox" data-service="fifth-button" />
        <span class="control__button">тык пять</span>
    </label>
</form>
```

Теперь, это маштабируемый код, можете хоть 10 кнопок обработать и если Вам нужно куда-то отправлять данные с выбранных инпутов, Вам всего лишь останется добавить кнопку для отправки в разметку формы, повесить листенер на форму(которая уже есть) и написать обработчик на событие submit и все готово!)

Comment: Добавьте себе 4 кнопу, раз уж вы решили глобально все сделать и насладитесь ошибкой ) При четвертой кнопке, можно тыкать все! Это к вашему комментарию [про динамическое число](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1491623/%d0%91%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85/1491641?noredirect=1#comment2674101_1491641)

Comment: Все работает отлично) 3 нажаты, одна заблокирована

Comment: Я даже дальше пойду и пятую добавлю))

Comment: Если Вы о том , что одна кнопка, блокируется, да, я об этом и говорил, что нужна глобальная переменная(в рамках модуля), но если нужно, я просо напишу ее так же динамически в состоянии и все, она будет не то что-бы глобальная в рамках модуля, а глобальная в рамках одного объекта в замыкании)) Это сила паттерна mvc))